# How to implement a Bottom Navigation Bar with a cradled Floating Action Button (FAB) in Nativescript?

Tags: angular, material-design, nativescript, floating-action-button, bottombar

I need to implement a Bottom Navigation Bar with a cradled Floating Action Button (FAB) centered horizontally, in Native-script (Angular/Typescript) like this:

[image: BottomAppBar with a cradled FAB]

Any thoughts on how to implement this feature?

There are 2 Nativescript plugins that might by combined to achieve the final result:
[Floating Action Button](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-floatingactionbutton)
and
[Bottom Navigation](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-bottom-navigation)
but when trying to apply a css clip-path property to the bottom navigation bar to create the cradle effect for the center FAB it doesn't work.

Here are Some hints on [how to implement it using Android](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708):

In addition, there is a solution that is quite near, but is just missing the "cradle"/"gap" efect I'm looking for to achieve:
[How to create a custom navigation bar in NativeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693077/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-bar-in-nativescript)

Comment: "I've tried to use a css clip-path property on the bottom navigation bar to create the cradle effect for the center floating button but it doesn't work."

Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom navigation bar in NativeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693077/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-bar-in-nativescript)

Answer (score 0):

actually, this implementation, need to be done with the `bottomappbar` component from material components.

this is the [repo](https://github.com/Akylas/nativescript-material-components) where you can find an initial implementation of that component, feel free to contribute